# How to send data on websocket close in react/nextjs on reload or tab close

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, websocket

I am making a web app where i want to show online/offline status of user. For that i need to listen to close and open events of websocket.

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws_url', 'token');
ws.onclose = (e) => {
   const data = {
     type: "offline",
     userId: "someid"
   }
   ws.send(JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

• You have create a function first to handle the `WebSocket` close event and send your data. You already have this part in your code:

```
const handleWebSocketClose = () => {
  const data = {
    type: "offline",
    userId: "someid"
  };
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

• you can use the `beforeunload` event to call this function

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function YourComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Add an event listener for beforeunload
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleWebSocketClose);

    // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleWebSocketClose);
    };
  }, []);

  // Your component logic here...

  return (
    // Your component JSX here...
  );
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Yes, i was able to solve the problem by doing the same!!

Answer (score 1):

Using useEffect you can pass the functions on component destroy, just use "return" isnide https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#usage